# "No ESLint configuration found" error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, eslint, grunt-eslint

Recently, we've upgraded to [ESLint 3.0.0](http://eslint.org/blog/2016/07/eslint-v3.0.0-released) and started to receive the following message running the `grunt eslint` task:

```
> $ grunt eslint
Running "eslint:files" (eslint) task
Warning: No ESLint configuration found. Use --force to continue.
```

Here is the `grunt-eslint` configuration:

```
var lintTargets = [
    "<%= app.src %>/**/*/!(*test|swfobject)+(.js)",
    "test/e2e/**/*/*.js",
    "!test/e2e/db/models/*.js"
];
module.exports.tasks = {
    eslint: {
        files: {
            options: {
                config: 'eslint.json',
                fix: true,
                rulesdir: ['eslint_rules']
            },
            src: lintTargets
        }
    }
};
```

What should we do to fix the error?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to swap `config` with `configFile`. Then :

1. Create **`eslint.json`**  file and
2. Point the right location of it (relative to **`Gruntfile.js`** file)
3. Place some configuration in that file (**`eslint.json`**), i.e.:

.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "eqeqeq": "off",
        "curly": "warn",
        "quotes": ["warn", "double"]
    }
}
```

for more examples, go [here](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring).

Comment: Yeah, `configFile` worked as well. Looks like we were using `config` which did not have any effect, but worked since eslint 2 searched for it by default. Now that we've migrated to eslint 3 and the default config filenames changed, eslint does not find the config automatically and this reveals that we should have used `configFile` from the beginning. This is the theory I have now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I just tackled the configuration recently, so avoided legacy problems.

Answer (score 54):

I've had the same error. It seems to need configuration.

Go to your project root & run in terminal

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init
```

Comment: I also need to update node to v12 for this to work

Comment: `node_modules\.bin\eslint --init` on Windows

Comment: Yo can use this instead. `npm init @eslint/config`

Answer (score 46):

The error you are facing is because your configuration is not present.
To configure the eslint type

**eslint --init**

then configure as your requirement.

then execute the project again.

Comment: Executing this command from the root will produce `bash: eslint: command not found`. Really worth mentioning that it should be executed from the `/node_modules/.bin`

Answer (score 16):

I hade the same problem with Gulp and running "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1" version.
I had to rename config: to configFile in Gulp task

```
.pipe(lint({configFile: 'eslint.json'}))
```

Answer (score 8):

For those having the same problem, this is how we've fixed it.

Following the [Requiring Configuration to Run](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-3.0.0#requiring-configuration-to-run) migration procedure, we had to **rename `eslint.json` to `.eslintrc.json`** which is one of the default ESLint config file names now.

We've also removed the `config` grunt-eslint option.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new file on the root directory called .eslintrc.json file:

```
 {
    "parserOptions": {
         "ecmaVersion": 6,
         "sourceType": "module",
         "ecmaFeatures": {
             "jsx": true
         }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": "error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the steps
1.create eslint config file name eslintrc.json
2.place the code as given below

```
gulp.src(jsFiles)
        // eslint() attaches the lint output to the "eslint" property
        // of the file object so it can be used by other modules.
        .pipe(eslint({configFile: 'eslintrc.json'}))
        // eslint.format() outputs the lint results to the console.
        // Alternatively use eslint.formatEach() (see Docs).
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        // To have the process exit with an error code (1) on
        // lint error, return the stream and pipe to failAfterError last.
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```

Answer (score 2):

## Webpack

I had eslint.rc file in my root project directory but event though
I was getting error.
Solution was to add exclude property to "eslint-loader" rule config:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          // eslint options (if necessary)
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We faced this problem today and realized, that the issue was not caused inside the project that we were working on, but inside a package that we had a link on using the command:

```
yarn link
```

Which is a feature often useful to test out new features or when trying to debug an issue in a package that manifests itself in another project.
We solved it by either removing the link, or in case of ember.js disabling the developer mode of our addon package.

**index.js**

```
module.exports = {
    isDevelopingAddon: function() {
      return false;
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('eslint',function(){
return gulp.src(['src/*.js'])
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
});


`touch .eslintrc`  instead of .eslint
```

these two steps may help you!

Answer (score 1):

Run the command **ember init**.
When it asks for overwriting the existing file(s). Type n to skipping overwriting the file.
Now it will automatically create required files like .eslintrc, etc.

For me the same issue occurred when i copied my folder except dist, dist_production and node_modules folder to another system and tried running **ember build**.