# why do i get a error when trying to "npm run serve"?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I have no idea what this error means anyone knows what a possible fix could be?

```
Failed to compile.

./src/main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: No ESLint configuration found.
    at Config.getLocalConfigHierarchy (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint\lib\config.js:268:39)
    at Config.getConfigHierarchy (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint\lib\config.js:192:43)
    at Config.getConfigVector (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint\lib\config.js:299:21)
    at Config.getConfig (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint\lib\config.js:342:29)
    at processText (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:181:33)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:690:40)
    at lint (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:263:17)
    at transform (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:237:18)
    at C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\loader-fs-cache\index.js:127:18
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\George\desktop\vuejsprojects\website\node_modules\loader-fs-cache\index.js:31:14)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:273:13)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No ESLint configuration found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173326/no-eslint-configuration-found-error)

Answer (score 1):

> **Local Installation and Usage**

If you want to include ESLint as part of your project's build system, we recommend installing it locally. You can do so using npm:

`npm install eslint --save-dev`

You should then setup a configuration file:

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init`

After that, you can run ESLint in your project's root directory like this:

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint yourfile.js`

---

> **Configuration**

**Note:** If you are coming from a version before 1.0.0 please see the [migration guide](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-1.0.0).

After running `eslint --init`, you'll have a `.eslintrc` file in your directory. In it, you'll see some rules configured like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "quotes": ["error", "double"]
    }
}
```

To know more: [Getting Started with ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/4.0.0/user-guide/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error weeks ago, i ran this on the terminal of my project and solved it:

```sh
npm install eslint -g -D

eslint --init
```

I took it from here:
https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-argon-design-system/issues/34